# JOGL and javax.media

Tags: java, jogl

I was trying out a simple tutorial for JOGL with eclipse:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jogl/jogl_installation.htm

I did as shown, but for some reason all of the javax.media includes are invalid:
The import javax.media cannot be resolved

I imported all of the mentioned jars into the build path. I've done lots of other projects, but importing jars always worked flawlessly for me.

To my impression I either have the wrong jars, I am missing something, or something is broken with the importing.

This is where I got the jars:
http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/

Comment: This tutorial isn't good, JOGL works with OpenJDK too, not only with Oracle Java, several paths are wrong, some titles are inconsistent with the screen captures, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use that, it's very outdated, use these instead:

- [Downloading_and_installing_JOGL](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL)
- [Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE)

`javax.media` is the previous location where in the older jogl versions the `GL` objects were

Comment: elect is right, please look at this bug report to understand when and why it was done: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=682

Comment: Thanks for the clarification  gouesse.
Elect, unfortunately I can't upvote yet.

Comment: @DajgoroLabinac, don't worry, the important thing is that you have solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse suggested adding the com.jogamp.jogl project to my project, and when I did that the problem was solved.
Still not sure why just adding the mentioned jars did not work.